# Broadcasting a service to Wifi network in Android

Tags: android, service, wifi, synchronization, broadcast

I am working on **Android** project in which i am syncing contacts and calendar with Mac via local WiFi connection and Here I have to notify WiFi network about the device existence(i.e,**broadcasting advertisement**) so that When Mac performs scan-devices operation my device must be detected,. so for that i need to broadcast a service to WiFi network,. can anybody help me how i can achieve this...?

and the broadcasting service must contain Android device information,. so which type of packet will it be...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android-mdns`  for broadcasting. for more information have a look at https://github.com/changyy/android-mdns.